# How to start iOS application from safari browser after fitbit login

Tags: ios, swift, fitbit, ios-universal-links

After finishing the fitbit login, I want to go back to my application, but I get an alert:

> Cannot open application

I added the `url scheme` to the info.plist.

```
this is info.plist details:

 <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>applinks:com.360medlink.Tavie</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fitbittavie://</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
and the redirect url in fitbit dev settings is fitbittavie://
```

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please provide details of your link as well as your custom URL scheme configuration (the relevant parts of your info.plist)

Comment: Please update your question rather than adding it in comments.

Comment: sorry this is the first time that I ask a question in stackoverflow. I updated  my question plz check it.

Comment: Your URL scheme should not include the `://`, just the scheme itself.

Comment: @jcaron thank you so much you made my day it works now

Comment: Added it as an answer, feel free to accept or up vote it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you defined the scheme in the `Info.plist` file with `://` appended.

The scheme should be specified by itself, without the `://`.